# Javascript JSON parse problem with decoded POST request data

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I get base64 data as an answer to a POST request.

It's decoded the following way (based on the documentation of the REST API):

```
let buf = Buffer.from(base64, "base64");
buf = buf.slice(4);
    
let data = gunzipSync(buf).toString()
console.log(data) // -> {"Code":200,"Value":"8e286fdb-aad2-43c6-87b1-1c6c0d21808a","Route":""}
console.log(data.length) // -> 140 -> Seems weird? Shouldn't it be 70?
```

Problem:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(data)) -> SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 1
```

I tried to delete all white characters via replace(/\s/g,''), tried decoding with toString("utf8"), etc.
Nothing helps. The only thing that could help is the weird wrong length described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your buffer is UTF-16 encoded and contains `\0` bytes, like `{·"·C·o·d·e·"·=·…` (with `·` representing `\0`), that's why it's double the expected length. The `\0` bytes don't print when you output the buffer with `console.log()`, that's why the output seems to be correct.

Decode the buffer before JSON-parsing it.

```
var buffer = Buffer.from(base64, "base64");
var str = buffer.toString('utf16le');

console.log(str)                // -> {"Code":200,"Value":"8e286fdb-aad2-43c6-87b1-1c6c0d21808a","Route":""}
console.log(str.length)         // -> 70

console.log(JSON.parse(str))    // -> { Code: 200, Value: '8e286fdb-aad2-43c6-87b1-1c6c0d21808a', Route: '' }
```

In general, never work with buffers as if they were strings. Buffers are *always* encoded in some way, that is their fundamental, defining difference from strings. You **must** decode them before outputting their contents as text.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think of the utf16 possibility.

Comment: @Samo The double length is a dead giveaway. Also `\0` is legal in JS strings, but it's not legal in JSON, that's why `JSON.parse()` fails. That it fails at position 1 tells you the byte order of the UTF-16, in this case the little-endian `{·"·C·o·d·e·`, i.e. `utf16le`. The less common big-endian variant `·{·"·C·o·d·e` would fail parsing at position 0.